# 401 error message by retrieving author information from Scopus API

Tags: api, http-status-code-401, scopus

I am trying to use your Scopus API to retrieve the publications that a certain author has, but I am facing a 401 error message in the browser console:

```
GET https://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/57196038163?apiKey=7f59af901d2d86f78a1fd60c1bf9426a&httpAccept=application/json 401
statusCode: "AUTHORIZATION_ERROR"
statusText: "The requestor is not authorized to access the requested view or fields of the resource"
```

The API key is attached with my website URL

[image]
Please check the following page which generates the error:
https://evo-ml.com/raneem/scopus2.html

Code:

```
<script>
fetch('https://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/57196038163?apiKey=7f59af901d2d86f78a1fd60c1bf9426a&httpAccept=application/json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch((error) => {console.error('Error:', error);});
</script>
```

I also tried to test it through the URL: https://dev.elsevier.com/retrieval.html but it seems that there is a problem there too.

Note: I am testing it through the API key I got from the website (which I can't share here). the one I've provided is the testing API key from the website.

Comment: were you able to find the solution ?

Comment: No. I sent an email to their support and no answer

Comment: I guess the api is not working anymore as it is not working on their testing page too

Comment: I am facing the same error. Any update?

Comment: No. Not working and they did not respond till now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your API Key does not have the correct service level to get the results you require from this API.

I see you have contacted support on this topic, and I'm sure they will get to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Their testing API is not working as well. They also did not respond since then

Comment: @user3631926 did you managed to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the network that you are using when sending the request. It should be the institution network, the same where the domain provided with the api key is registered.

[image: scopys api]

Here is what you can read from the [FAQ](https://dev.elsevier.com/support.html):

[image: scopus faq]

So if you are working from home the best way is to use VPN and/or remote desktop to send the request directly from the computer that is connected to the instutional network.

Comment: Elsevier provides an Institution Token that will enable you to access the APIs outside of your institutional network.

Please contact their support team who will help you out with this

https://service.elsevier.com/app/contact/supporthub/researchproductsapis/